# Cant figure out what I'm doing wrong with Java if else statements

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong here? I need this to sort the numbers using if, else if and else statements. So far I haven't figure what it is that is wrong with the pseudo-code I received.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj3
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter three whole numbers <integers> to be sorted");
       int n1,n2,n3;
       n1 = input.nextInt();
       n2 = input.nextInt();
       n3 = input.nextInt();
       if (n1 <= n2 || n1 <= n3) {
           min = n1;
           if (n2 <= n3){
               mid= n2;
               max = n3;
           } else{
               mid = n3;
               max = n2;
           } 
       else if(n2 <= n3) {
           min = n2;
       } else {
           min = n3;
       }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read a tutorial on `if-elseif-else` statements. Note the order I put them in.

Comment: Try to pair the braces, it's evident that this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I believe the second if is supposed to be nested, would that change anything?

Comment: If you format your code, it will become more obvious.

Comment: Its not my code it was sent to me by my organization, I would have done it a completely different way, but my boss insists it be done as such.

Comment: If you format the code that was sent to you by your organization, it will become more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for closing this just before I understood

Answer (score 1):

I have formatted your post. See your code carefully

```
if (n1 <= n2 || n1 <= n3) {
    min = n1;
    if (n2 <= n3) {
        mid= n2;
        max = n3;
    } else {  
        mid = n3;
        max = n2;
    }
else if(n2 <= n3) {
    min = n2;
}
```

You are missing closing bracket of `if (n1 <= n2 || n1 <= n3)`. Always practice properly indented and formatted coding to avoid these kinds of errors.

You can auto format your whole code by pressing these keys in `eclipse`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to indent the selected part of you code.

Comment: Ok as suggested I cleaned its formatting up now I am getting a "Cannot find symbol error" what am I doing wrong

Comment: @user3309169 Can you please add the update in your question with the updated code?

Comment: Standby I will post it now

Comment: `if (n1 <= n2 || n1 <= n3) {
    min = n1; 
 if (n2 <= n3){
    mid= n2;
    max = n3;
    } else if (n2 <= n3) {
        mid = n3;
        max = n2;
    } 
    else{
    min = n2;
    }
}`